# Passing method of object as an argument

Tags: c++

I have to do a TP for my school, using part of a code that I haven't written.
The prototype of the function is the following :

```
 using Callback =
  std::function< bool(std::string const& request, std::string& response) >;

TCPServer::TCPServer(Callback const& callback) :
callback_(callback) {
  // signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);  // ignore nasty SIGPIPEs
}
```

The function I would like to use is a member function of a class named `whole`. I am using this code :

```
// cree l'objet qui gère les données
// create the object that manages the data
    shared_ptr<Whole> whole(new Whole());
    whole->createPhoto("Photo1", "undefined/paths", 0, 0);
    // cree le TCPServer
    shared_ptr<TCPServer> server = new TCPServer(&whole::processRequest)
```

But for some reason, this doesn't seem to compile. I get the error :
"error: ‘whole’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
shared_ptr server = new TCPServer(&whole::processRequest);"

Can someone help me ? I have no idea which syntax i should use.

Here is the the example given by my teacher to implement the class TCPserver :

```
new TCPServer( [&](std::string const& request, std::string& response) {

    // the request sent by the client to the server
    std::cout << "request: " << request << std::endl;

    // the response that the server sends back to the client
    response = "RECEIVED: " + request;

    // return false would close the connection with the client
    return true;
  });
```

Comment: post the full compilation error message

Comment: It's not strictly required, but I suggest translating the comments into English as well. It would be helpful to readers.

Comment: Did you include the header file that declares Whole?

Comment: Here is the complete error message : "// cree l'objet qui gère les données
    shared_ptr<Whole> whole(new Whole());
    whole->createPhoto("Photo1", "undefined/paths", 0, 0);
    // cree le TCPServer
    shared_ptr<TCPServer> server = new TCPServer(&whole::processRequest)".

Comment: For the comments, they are pretty irrelevant in this case, it would help to understand the global problem, but i just need to get the syntax proper for the call of function.

Comment: I think it should be `&Whole::processRequest`

Comment: @Jack Lilhammers didn't work :( But it wouldnt have had any sense since i need to pass as an argument the function linked to the object).

For the record, here is the call of function given as an exemple in my TP, which compile properly :

new TCPServer( [&](std::string const& request, std::string& response) {
    std::cout << "request: " << request << std::endl;

    response = "RECEIVED: " + request;
    return true;
  });

Comment: semi-colon missing at the end of the `new TCPServer(&whole::processRequest)` statement.

Comment: Don't post the error message in comments. Include it in the question.

Comment: @selbie thx, but still not working (i've got the same error)

Comment: I don't think you can pass the address to a member function of a particular object. That's not how C++ works, IIRC methods are stored in static vtables. In fact if you add a method the size of the object does not grow.

Comment: You can read about std::function here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/function/

Comment: You can also look at the way Qt signals and slots are connected. You need to pass the member function **and** the object which calls that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming that Whole::processRequest is declared as :

```
bool Whole::proessRequest(string const&, string&);
```

So instead of this, where there's no instance of `Whole` being passed, just a pointer to a function with no instance of `Whole` associated with it:

```
shared_ptr<TCPServer> server = new TCPServer(&whole::processRequest)
```

Do this instead.  Create lambda wrapper that captures your `whole` shared_ptr instance and invokes the method as you would expect.

```
auto fn = [whole](std::string const& request, std::string& response) -> bool {
    return whole->processRequest(request, response);
};
shared_ptr<TCPServer> server = new TCPServer(fn);
```